# it says "error: failed linking file resources." and all the R are red

Tags: android

[all of the sudden the resource file cant be accessed ,because when i try to type in setContentView(R..) it just says can't resolve the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZtSTn.png)

Comment: Please post the relevant code in the post and not as a screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just go to `Build` -> `Clean Project`, `Rebuild Project` or `Make Project` and you're good to go.

OR `File` -> `Invalidate Caches / Restart`

or check your `imports` at the top and look for your `R` if it is color `gray` you can delete it then try to import it again.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes I get this error and Sometimes Android Studio is not compiling the new code and it's deploying the old apk. I fix this by

doing a clean on Android Project.

closing the emulator.

restarting the adb server by running adb kill-server and adb start-server from the command line.