# Android studio Error: failed linking file resources

Tags: android

Hello I was coding in android studio and suddenly this error started. tried some solutions they didnt work. any help would be great . thank you very much!

```
       Android resource linking failed
Output:  C:\Users\Liad Rosenberg\Desktop\Application2\Application2\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_ent_buil.xml:24: error: attribute android:TextSize not found.
error: failed linking file resources.

Command: C:\Users\Liad Rosenberg\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar\1ad82ce000af4f9770f30f2680cd1694\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows\aapt2.exe link -I\
        D:\Users\Liad Rosenberg\AppData\platforms\android-28\android.jar\
        --manifest\
        C:\Users\Liad Rosenberg\Desktop\Application2\Application2\app\build\intermediates\merged_manifests\debug\processDebugManifest\merged\AndroidManifest.xml\
        -o\
        C:\Users\Liad Rosenberg\Desktop\Application2\Application2\app\build\intermediates\processed_res\debug\processDebugResources\out\resources-debug.ap_\
        -R\
        @C:\Users\Liad Rosenberg\Desktop\Application2\Application2\app\build\intermediates\incremental\processDebugResources\resources-list-for-resources-debug.ap_.txt\
        --auto-add-overlay\
        --java\
        C:\Users\Liad Rosenberg\Desktop\Application2\Application2\app\build\generated\not_namespaced_r_class_sources\debug\processDebugResources\r\
        --custom-package\
        com.example.liadrosenberg.application\
        -0\
        apk\
        --output-text-symbols\
        C:\Users\Liad Rosenberg\Desktop\Application2\Application2\app\build\intermediates\symbols\debug\R.txt\
        --no-version-vectors
Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows Daemon #0
```

Any Help?
Thanks
    tried that: [it says "error: failed linking file resources." and all the R are red](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50053822/it-says-error-failed-linking-file-resources-and-all-the-r-are-red) Didnt worked. What else can I do to make it works back?
Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

go to activity_ent_buil.xml line 24 then replace

```
android:TextSize
```

with

```
android:textSize
```

Answer (score 1):

First, try with CleanProject in tools tab. If that does not next sync project and check. If nothing works in File -> Invalidate cache and restart. It will come up with clean & clear resources linking.